# Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown database 'crm_ventas_conduit'

Tags: mysql

Me surgió una nueva duda, ya instale en mi servidor lo necesario para ejecutar mis app web, de echo volví a crear mi DB igual que en desarrollo pero en el servidor, en la carpeta de htdocs puse mis códigos PHP, y verifique que en la carpeta de Mysql se generara la DB, cuando ejecuto en el explorador mi consulta me sale esto:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown database 'crm_ventas_conduit' in C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\consulta_usuario.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\consulta_usuario.php(10): mysqli_select_db(Object(mysqli), 'crm_ventas_cond...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\consulta_usuario.php on line 10
```

pero en desarrollo me funciona sin problemas, lo único diferente que hice es que en desarrollo mi contraseña para la DB es root y cuando instale MySQL en el servidor puse una contraseña distinta

Comment: cuando entras a `phpmyadmin` en producción, puedes verificar que la base de datos exista? El error no refiere a un problema de usuario/contraseña sino que directamente no encuentra la BDD según veo.

Comment: Si, en la carta de htcdocs esta otra carpeta de nombre Mysql y ahí se genera la carpeta crm_ventas_conduit y dentro de ella están las tablas generadas

Comment: Bien, entiendo. Pero puedes visualizarlas en `phpmyadmin`? Mas allá de verlas en el explorador a la carpeta y los archivos, entrando a http://localhost/phpmyadmin/  la puedes ver e interactuar con ella?

Comment: No la puedo ver desde phpmyadmin, lo que hice para instalar hpmyadmin es según lo que vi en un tutorial,  instale el xxamp en el servidor, después instale Mysql y después  descargue phpmyadmin 5.2.0 desde internet lo descomprimi y lo puse en la carpeta htcdocs de xxamp y lo renombre como phpmyadmin5 y ya lo veo en el explorador, pero no veo la DB

Comment: y ahora me sale este error en phpmyadmin Abrir nueva ventana de phpMyAdmin
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Tienes un problema en la instalación del motor de Mysql y aparte del phpMyAdmin. He tenido problemas teniendo instalado Mysql y XAMPP en el pasado. XAMPP instala el motor de base de datos de MariaDB y también instala phpMyAdmin. Prueba desisntalando todo y volviendo a instalar. Sigue algun tutorial confiable. Sobre que SO lo estas instalando?

Comment: en windows server 2019

Comment: Desinstala todo lo que instalaste, todo todito. [Acá hay un tutorial completo](https://codingsight.com/how-to-install-and-configure-xampp-software-on-windows-server-2019/) de la instalación de XAMPP en ese entorno (WS2019). Espero te sirva. El problema, sin dudas está en la instalación de XAMPP

Comment: Gracias @Liyo , realice las cosas como me comentaste, ahora creo mi DB y ya la puedo ver desde mi localhost/phpmyadmin, si se encuentra y con la información que le genere, pero ahora el problema es que cuando ejecuto mis scripts me marca que no encuentra la DB y en desarrollo la veo sim problemas, podras orientarme me sale el siguiente error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown database 'crm_ventas_conduit' in

Comment: estas utilizando una cadena de conexión correcta en tu conector Mysql? Sería de ayuda si editas la pregunta y agregas el código que está fallando por favor. Gracias

Comment: Gracias liyo, si voy a editar la pregunta, pero vi algo en mi servidor que me gustaria si me puedes orientar, en MySQL 8.0 Commsnd Line Client cuando ejecuto el comando show databases no se ve mi DB aun cuando en el phpmy admin si la veo, y cuando ejecuto el mismo comando pero en desarrollo  si se ve la DB, siento que por ahí va el problema o no?

Comment: Si, correcto. Como te comenté anteriormente, Tener instalado MySQL y XAMPP juntos, requiere otra configuración. Tu cadena de conexión a la BD desde PHP está haciendo referencia al motor del MySQL, cuando en realidad la BDD está alojada en el MariaDB de XAMPP Revisa los puertos que tiene asignado cada motor y conectate al puerto correspondiente (MySQL por defecto es 3306).